# Securing my ASP.net MVC3 Website aganist "Click jacking"

Tags: visual-studio-2010, asp.net-mvc-3

Recently I was flipping through some security issues faced by websites. Fortunately come across a new term "Click jacking"

I understood that this attack happens only if my website is loadable in an IFrame.

Further investigation helped to know that setting "x-frame-options" to  "DENY" prevent the website been loaded in IFrame

But I Don't know how to implement this as I am very new to this domain?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

In your Global.asax you can add the following

```
protected void Application_BeginRequest(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    HttpContext.Current.Response.AddHeader("x-frame-options", "SAMEORIGIN");
}
```

Comment: Thanks for sorting out the problem

Answer (score 4):

**Just put following code under `<system.webServer>` section in `web.config` file**

```
<httpProtocol>
  <customHeaders>
    <add name="X-Frame-Options" value="DENY"/>
  </customHeaders>
</httpProtocol>
```

> **NOTE** : The `X-Frame-Options` header may contain one of three
> tokens.You either add any of these.Each one has its own significance.
>
> - DENY
> - SAMEORIGIN
> - ALLOW-FROM origin
>
> For details visit MSDN blog : [Combating ClickJacking With X-Frame-Options](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/ieinternals/2010/03/30/combating-clickjacking-with-x-frame-options/)

Answer (score 2):

Have a look at this:

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/HTTP/X-Frame-Options#Configuring_Apache

It's basically a response header sent out on all responses. You can code your site to do this for each individual page, but a better approach, if you are able to edit the configuration for JUST YOUR SITE, is to handle it there...

Both APACHE and IIS should have options for this - the IIS one seems to be here:

http://support.microsoft.com/kb/2694329

Answer (score 0):

For people looking to protect .net 5.0 MVC / Razor pages, add the following to your `Configure` method in `Startup.cs`:

```cs
app.Use(async (context, next) =>
{
    context.Response.Headers.Add("X-Frame-Options", "DENY");
    await next();
});
```

### Links

- [OWasp DotNet Security Cheat Sheet](https://cheatsheetseries.owasp.org/cheatsheets/DotNet_Security_Cheat_Sheet.html)
- [Hanselman blog post on security headers](https://www.hanselman.com/blog/easily-adding-security-headers-to-your-aspnet-core-web-app-and-getting-an-a-grade)